# I am not able to access the if statement inside the controller in angularjs and ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to create an application using crypto.js in which i can convert plain text to cypher text. My logic is as given below

```
  $scope.encrypt = function () {

    if ($scope.message != '' && $scope.passphrase != '' ) {
      alert('clicked');
      $scope.cypher = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt($scope.message, $scope.passphrase);

      $scope.cypherString = String($scope.cypher);

      $scope.message = '';

      $scope.feedBack = 'The text was successfully encrypted.';

      $scope.status = 'success';

    } else {

      $scope.feedBack = 'You need to enter a key phrase to encrypt text.';

      $scope.status = 'error';

    }

  }
```

But even if i enter both the fields i am unable to get the encryted message i always see the error message .. below is a link of the plnkr
http://plnkr.co/edit/3g1N09?p=preview

Comment: Why did you assigned $scope.message=''; like this?

Comment: I guess they were causing the error.. Thanks for rectifying it. But now after i have removed those the code goes into the if block but lines i am getting " Cannot read property 'words' of undefined" error in the console - any idea why ?

Comment: Ya check now .. i am getting the same error " Cannot read property 'words' of undefined"

Comment: That error is because i have removed the $scope.message='' and etc .. i initialized them because i have to show them as strings or elze i am getting this error

Comment: update your plunker link

Comment: To assign sample text work fine.$scope.message = 'test'; and $scope.passphrase = 'test'; So error in your ng-model getting data

Comment: Dude its done .. thank you for your time .. the problem was
$scope.message != '' && $scope.passphrase != ''
changed to 
$scope.message != null && $scope.passphrase != null

Answer (score 0):

Change the function like this:

```
 $scope.encrypt = function (message,passphrase) {
if (message && passphrase ) {
  alert('clicked');
  $scope.cypher = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, passphrase);
```

And the view to this:

```
<button class="button button-block button-balanced" ng-click="encrypt(message,passphrase)" >
```

And remove the $scope.message = '' assignements...